# ARIA for adding or removing a DIV

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

When adding or removing a DIV to HTML, what ARIA attributes should I use to signal screen readers? I've been using ARIA-HIDDEN when showing or hiding DIVs.

Comment: `display:none` is more than adequate for screen readers. Are you trying to tell a user that it has disappeared? Have you looked at `aria-live`?

Comment: I can't use `display:none` because I'm adding and deleting the DIV, not showing and hiding one that already exists.

`var send = $('input[name="submit_button"]');
$('input[name="submit_button"]').click(function () {
        var email = $('input[name="first_email"]').val();
        var confemail = $('input[name="second_email"]').val();
        if(email != confemail) {
   $('<div id="msg"">The e-mail addresses do not match.</div><br clear="all">').insertBefore($(send));
            return false;
        } else {
   $('#msg').remove();
            return true;
        }
    })`

Comment: Then you will need `aria-live` on a container. See answer from slugolicious below.

Answer (score 2):

If adding and removing elements is a significant event and you want the screen reader to know about it, then you'll need a combination of `aria-live='assertive'` (so that it's announced immediately) and `aria-relevant='all'`.  These should be set on the parent container - the `<div>` that will contain the new `<div>`s you're creating.

By default, aria-relevant will only announce changes in text or the addition of an element.  If you want to notify the screen reader that the `<div>` was removed, then the value will need to be `'all'`.

http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-live 
http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-relevant

Comment: Will those ARIA attributes take effect if they're added to the parent DIV in the script, instead of hard-coded in the HTML?

Comment: They need to be on a container that is there (effectively) at page render (or at least prior to adding something else into that you want to be announced). Here is a resource that may help: http://juicystudio.com/article/wai-aria_live-regions_updated.php

Comment: I modified my script to include this line:

`$(send).parent().attr('aria-live','assertive').attr('aria-relevant','all');`